# Get a data from website by StreamReader c#

Tags: c#, html-parsing, streamreader

I solved the problem. it must be like this :

```
 int baslangic = Kodlar.IndexOf("<img src=") + 3;
            int bitis = Kodlar.Substring(baslangic).IndexOf(">");
```

I'm trying to parse html with streamreader.

My purpose is , get all images links.

My code is :

```
string site;
            site = $"http://tr.socialll.net/search?name={isim}+{soyad}&location={sehir}&gender=both";


            WebRequest talep = HttpWebRequest.Create(site);
            WebResponse cevap = talep.GetResponse();
            StreamReader oku = new StreamReader(cevap.GetResponseStream());
            string Kodlar = oku.ReadToEnd();
            int start = Kodlar.IndexOf("<img>") + 4;
            int finish = Kodlar.Substring(start).IndexOf("</img>");

            Console.WriteLine(Kodlar.Substring(start, finish));
            Console.Read();
```

I want to get here :

```
<img src="https://iasdai.net/img/user/128x128/116a38953-MWOVJ4aS250K5U.jpg" onerror="this.src='http://tr.socialll.net/img/alternative.png';" alt="">
```

But i get an error message like this :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HtmlDocument class and get all links by their tags through the predefined method GetElementsByTagName(String)

Answer (score 0):

One problem I spotted was how you are searching for the `img` element

```
int start = Kodlar.IndexOf("<img>") + 4;
int finish = Kodlar.Substring(start).IndexOf("</img>");
```

Compare this to the actual image element, it begins with `<img src="` and ends with `>`. There is no `</img>` at the end of it, so neither were found and both the `start` and `finish` variables were set to **-1**. Once you tried to use these in your `substring` commands they threw the *out of range* error

So what you would probably want to do is adjust your **start** and **finish** definitons to something like this:

```
int start = Kodlar.IndexOf("<img ") + 4;
int finish = Kodlar.Substring(start).IndexOf(">");
```

You may need to double check the values to verify.